# How to debug this dynamic linking error on OSX?

Tags: macos, acrobat, adobe-reader

```
dyld: loaded: /Applications/Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.app/Contents/Frameworks/ICUConverter.framework/ICUConverter
dyld: unloaded: /Applications/Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.app/Contents/Frameworks/ICUConverter.framework/ICUConverter
2019-01-22 01:17:17.314 e-Deklaracje[2579:96645] Error loading /Applications/Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.app/Contents/Frameworks/ICUConverter.framework/ICUConverter:  dlopen(/Applications/Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.app/Contents/Frameworks/ICUConverter.framework/ICUConverter, 265): Library not loaded: @rpath/ICUData.framework/Versions/58.2/ICUData
  Referenced from: /Applications/Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.app/Contents/Frameworks/ICUConverter.framework/ICUConverter
  Reason: image not found
```

This is from an application loading acrobat reader. The error says it can't load: `@rpath/ICUData.framework/Versions/58.2/ICUData`. Using `otool -l` I checked that acrobat reader executable has an RPATH entry with the right location.

```
Load command 18
          cmd LC_RPATH
      cmdsize 48
         path @executable_path/../Frameworks (offset 12)
```

So what is wrong? Maybe the RPATH entry should be present in `ICUConverter`? There is no such entry there.

Comment: What do you mean by "an application loading acrobat reader"? Is this your application? If so, how are you trying to load Acrobat Reader, and what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @NSGOD, it is application used to calculate your taxes available here: https://www.podatki.gov.pl/media/3103/e-deklaracjedesktop_11-0-1.air, where parent site for this link is here: https://www.podatki.gov.pl/e-deklaracje/aplikacja-e-deklaracje-desktop/. Probably you could easily reproduce it a it happens during probe of opening new form, somehow it uses Acrobat Reader under the hood as you could see then error: "Failed to load an application resource (Internal error)"

Comment: The important part of the error is `Library not loaded: @rpath/ICUData.framework/Versions/58.2/ICUData, Reason: image not found`. Does `ICUData` actually exist in that location?

Answer (score 0):

maybe not the exact solution but at least workaround is to downgrade your Adobe Reader to 11.0.10. You will be prompted in e-Deklaracje to choose proper Adobe Reader.
Restarting of e-Deklaracja could be needed.

Solution comes from: http://www.owsiak.org/and-now-for-something-completely-different-e-deklaracje-2019-macos/

By the way I tried it replaced Contents of Adobe Reader.app to use particular binaries instead of aliases but it didn't help.